# webgl drawArray intermediate results

Tags: javascript, webgl

```
    setMatrixUniforms();
    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, triangleVertexPositionBuffer.numItems);
```

Once the matrices are set, (for projection etc) the points passed to drawArrays will be projected accordingly and drawn. I would like to know if there is any way of obtaining the final positions of these transformed points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution is to recalculate the positions outside of WebGL with plain javascript and your matrix library.

For instance if you want to know what the point (0, 0, 0) becomes after you apply the model view matrix you would just multiply it with that matrix.

```
var point = [0, 0, 0];
var result = mat4.multiplyVec3(mvMatrix, point, []);
```

Or if you wanted the final transformed point which is outputted at the end of the vertex shader it is usually just your point multiplied by the model view matrix and then by the projection matrix.

```
// Create a model view projection matrix by multiplying the two matrices together
var mvpMatrix = mat4.create();
mat4.multiply(pMatrix, mvMatrix, mvpMatrix);

// Multiply the point (0,0,0) by the model view projection matrix to get the result
var point = [0, 0, 0, 1];
var result = mat4.multiplyVec4(mvpMatrix , point, []);
```

And if you wanted to know the final result for all of your vertices you would loop through each vertex and compute its result.

```
// Create a model view projection matrix by multiplying the two matrices together
var mvpMatrix = mat4.create();
mat4.multiply(pMatrix, mvMatrix, mvpMatrix);

var  results = [];

// Calculate the transformed points for each vertex
for(var i = 0; i < (vertices.length/3); i++) {
    var point = [vertices[i*3], vertices[i*3+1], vertices[i*3+2], 1];
    results[i] = mat4.multiplyVec4(mvpMatrix, point);
}
```

In the above example the `vertices` array is 1 dimensional.

Since this approach is so simple and you are recalculating what WebGL has already calculated, it might be too slow if you have to recalculate a large number of points. However for a lot of use cases this will work just fine.